# Java EE Specification vs Implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have recently started on Java EE and having a tough time understanding it. I have read some answers here on SO, but I still feel like there are some gaps in my understanding. Basically, Java EE is a specification and application servers like TOMCAT, Glassfish etc., have the concrete implementations. Also, anyone can provide implementation for EE.

So, I have downloaded `javax.sevlet-api-4.0.1-sources.jar` from Maven repo and I can see that they are just Interfaces and I assume we just use them to build the project?

In tomcat lib folder there is a `servlet-api.jar`. Is this the tomcat implementation of Servlet? And if it is, then is it possible to replace it with another servlet version implementation?

Now, Hibernate is the implementation of Persistence API. If I want to use Hibernate with Tomcat. I just need to add the Hibernate related jars to my application and can use them for both build and run? Without actually getting the contract classes.

Comment: By the way, *Java EE* is now known as *Jakarta EE* after having been donated by Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation. The handover is still in transition. But you can find the latest Javadoc for the various APIs at http://www.Jakarta.ee/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the servlet-api jar file when compiling your code, because that's where e.g. `HttpServletRequest` is. You don't need to include that jar with your application, because it is provided already by the Servlet Container you deploy your war file to, e.g. Tomcat.

With Tomcat, the *implementation* of the various servlet classes are in `catalina.jar`, at least for Tomcat 9, e.g. `ApplicationHttpRequest` is the class implementing `HttpServletRequest`. You don't need this to compile your code.

Comment: Thank you, is there any source that I can check to see how specification API and implementation work together.

Comment: @poolD That's a general question and simply explained. The *specification API* consists of the types used by the caller of the API. These types usually are mostly enums, interfaces, and abstract classes, but can be concrete classes too, e.g. for value classes. The *implementation* consists of classes implementing the API, and the caller doesn't need to use any of those classes directly, and is actually not allowed to use them.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of what happens under the hood because people say for eg: if javax.persistence is used in application then reference implementation like Hibernate, TopLink  can be changed at any time without changing any app code. how does it identifies the implementation. is there any config we'll specify?

Comment: @poolD "how does it identifies the implementation"* As a general question, that is way too broad, since every API will resolve that in different ways. For the Servlet API, the servlet container is the one calling your code, so it creates instances of whatever implementation class it wants to, before calling your code, passing that instance to you, as the declared interface.

Comment: @poolD E.g. when Tomcat calls your `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` method, it might internally create an instance of a `TomcatRequest` class that implements the `HttpServletRequest` interface, then pass that to your code.

Answer (score 4):

To be accurate, Tomcat is not a fully fledged Java EE container, it only handles part of the Java EE spec (mainly servlet, jsp, jndi and a few others).

And as Andreas wrote, you need `serlvet-api.jar` to compile your code (otherwise `HttpSerlvetRequest` will miss). But as Tomcat already provides it (as an interface) as well as an actual implementation, you should add it as a "provided" dependency in your maven file.